# Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, imageview, imagebutton

На эмеляторе запускается без проблем, а вот на 5-ти разных устройствах запустился только на одном, а на остальных тупо завершает ошибкой.

В логе ругается на `Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton` а конкретнее на первый `ImageButton`

Вот сама верстка

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="us.ethnicmedia.radiovmeste.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="150dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/play_active"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/pause"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Если удалить `ImageView` тогда запускается без ошибок и все работает((

Хотел узнать, где допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чем проблема!

Оказалось, что дизайнер дал картинки и для background картинка была слишком большого разрешения. Получается дизайнер не учел что это для мобильных устройств, а я не проверил разрешения))

Спасибо за внимание!